# Store type Class in an Array or ArrayList java

Tags: java, arrays, class

My primary goal here is just to have an Arraylist or array that holds type Class.  What would the easiest way to go about this?

I don't really want to create an object to just to call getClass().

```
Class[] classes = { someObject.getClass(), someObject1.getClass() };
```

The most ideal way to do this would be just to just call the name of the class.  Is this possible?

```
Class[] classes = { SomeObject, SomeObject1 };
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a static object that I hold onto and I want to see if it is an instanceOf whatever is in my array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

```
Class[] classes = { SomeObject.class, SomeObject1.class };
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitely looked passed this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this will help:

```
Class[] classes = {SomeObject.class, SomeObject1 .class };
```